# how can i make two subgroups appear the same number of times using regex?

Tags: python, regex

In regex:
I am having a problem matching the following language:

```
 L = {((aa) repeat n times)(b repeat n times) | n >=1 }
```

I tried to do `(aa)+b+`, but this cannot guarantee that `aa` and `b` occurs the same number of times.

Is there any simple way I can do this(in python?)?
Thanks.

Comment: `n` has to be the same, right? Eg `aaaab` fails, `aab` passes?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, n has to be same.

Comment: Regex isn't suitable for validating that things occur the same number of times. What language are you using?

Comment: Reopening because OP's tried something and the answer doesn't look obvious. I can't think of a way to do this off the top of my head. You may have to resort to using a method other than regex (which shouldn't be hard at all in Python)

Comment: ok, sorry guys, I think I might be wrong from the beginning, this Language L is derived by me from a **grammar**, so maybe this suggest if it is hard to use regex for some pattern, grammar can do it.

Comment: I mean, the problem is that the complexity class in the Chomsky hierarchy isn't sufficient to handle memory to store the prior count of `a`. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) which shows that you're trying to apply a FSA to solve a context-free language matching problem. OK, I know regex has lots of tricks that make it context free/sensitive or recursively enumerable but it's still a fundamental issue. I'd just do `s.count("a") == s.count("b") * 2 and re.fullmatch(r"a{2,}b+", s)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed, I recommend a simple recursive descent approach.

You can remove `aa` from the front and `b` from the back at the same time.

```py
def foo(s):
  if s == "":
    return True
  if s.startswith('aa') and s.endswith('b'):
    return foo(s[2:-1])
  else:
    return False
```